# How to provide different serializers based on incoming request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to provide different serializers based on incoming request for my categoryname Field in my model Role.

Here is what i have tried:

Here is my Full Details view.

```
class RoleDetails(PBDetailsViewMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Role
    table_name = "Roles" # For search and filter options (Redis key)
    required_groups= {
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],

    }
    required_permissions={
        'GET':['__all__'],
        'POST':['__all__'],

    }
    DEFAULT_QUERY_SETTINGS={
        'pageSize':500,
        'current':1,
        'sortOrder':[],
        'sortField':[],
        'visibleFields':['id', 'address1','address2','categoryname','owner','vat','date_created'],
        'filters':{}
    }

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


    def get_serializer_class(self):


        categoryname = Role.objects.filter(categoryname=categoryname, pk=pk1,  owner=owner)

        if self.request.method == 'GET' and self.request.user.has_perm('user.view_user'):
             return RoleSerializerDepth
        if self.request.method == 'PUT' and 'Developer' in categoryname:
           return RoleSerializerDeveloper
        if self.request.method == 'PUT' and 'Investor' in categoryname:
           return RoleSerializerInvestor
        if self.request.method == 'PUT' and 'Auditor' in categoryname:
            return RoleSerializerAuditor
        if self.request.method == 'PUT' and 'Educational' in categoryname:
           return RoleSerializerEducationalInstitution
        return RoleSerializerBasic


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Role.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Here is my model

```
class Role(models.Model):

    address1 = models.TextField(name="address1", max_length=150, null=True)
    address2 = models.TextField(name="address2", max_length=150, null=True)
    vat = models.CharField( max_length=100, null=True)
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, db_index=True)

    date_created = models.DateField(null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    is_passive = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='roles', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And my serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Role

from core.serializers import DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer
from user.serializers import CustomUserSimpleSerializer
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator


class RoleSerializerBasic(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer ,BasicSerializer,):
     owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username') #

     class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role #  Model to serialize
        fields =  ('address1', 'address2','vat','categoryname','date_created', 'owner')


        extra_kwargs = {
            'categoryname': {
                'validators': []
            }
       }
     def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        address1 = validated_data.pop['address1']
        address2 = validate_data.pop['address2']

        categoryname = validated_data.pop('categoryname')
        vat = validated_data.pop('vat')
        date_created = validated_data.pop('date_created')

        instance.save()
        return instance 






class RoleSerializerDepth(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username') 

    class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):

        model = Role #  Model to serialize
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {
                'validators': []
            }
        } 

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        address1 = validated_data.pop['address1']
        address2 = validate_data.pop['address2']

        categoryname = validated_data.pop('categoryname')
        vat = validated_data.pop('vat')
        date_created = validated_data.pop('date_created')

        instance.save()
        return instance






class RoleSerializerInvestor(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer ,BasicSerializer):

      class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role #  Model to serialize

        exclude = ('address1', 'address2')
        depth = 0 # How deep we want to serialize fk connections


class RoleSerializerAuditor(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

      class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role

        exclude = ('vat')
        depth = 0

class RoleSerializerDeveloper(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

      class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role

        exclude = ('address1')
        depth = 0

class RoleSerializerEducationalInstitution(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, BasicSerializer):

      class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
        model = Role

        exclude = ('vat')
        depth = 0
```

I want when categoryname of my incoming request contains 'Developer' to return all the fields. 
When the request contains Investor in the value, i want to exclude some fields and still be able to update my data. That is why i am trying to use different serializers.

I am having trouble understanding how to get the instance request in my get_serializer_class really.

The error i am getting is : local variable 'categoryname' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant view/viewset.

Comment: @heemayl I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

`generics.GenericAPIView` inherits from `views.APIView`, which sets the incoming `request` as an attribute of the `View` (`ViewSet`) instance (in the `dispatch` method); it will be available to all the view methods as an instance attribute i.e. in any method that has a reference to the instance (`self`), you can refer it via `self.request`.

So inside your `RoleDetails.get_serializer_class`, you can get the current `HttpRequest` instance via `self.request`.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* referencing `categoryname` and `pk1` and `owner` before declaring them.

You will have to  pass them in via the URL, something like this:

```
from django.urls import re_path
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(
        r"^roles/(?P<pk>.+)/(?P<categoryname>.+)/$", the_name_of_your_view),
]
```

Then those variables will be available as `self.kwargs` (and "owner" can be retrieved from `self.request.user`).

Alternatively, and probably a bit cleaner, would be to use ViewSets:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'roles', RoleViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

"categoryname" can be passed in as a query parameter [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params].